# How to get absolute value in solidity?

Tags: solidity, integers

In JavaScript, there is "Math.abs":

[image]

Is there a similar function in solidity itself or some other popular library such as SafeMath?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit funny that the Solidity documentation hints about such a function `abs` (https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/types.html) but I can't get it to compile at least in Remix. So I assume there is no such function and the documentation is just a bit off (wouldn't be the first time).

There are probably some libraries which contain that functionality but no idea which and where.

Anyway, it's easy to enough to implement it yourself - you gave the formula already :)

Note that you can't just cast `int` into `uint` and be done with it - it's not allowed. And even if it was, -1 should probably cast into Max(uint) - 1.

Comment: `Note that you can't just cast int into uint and be done with it ` - well, this is part of the reason I asked the question in the first place. I could do it myself, but there are always some gotchas in solidity, so relying on whatever is the community standard is the optimal solution most of the time.

Comment: There, added a PR to fix documentation: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/pull/7428

Comment: Fixed in newest documentation: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.12/types.html